# Trigger Button click without mouse

Tags: silverlight

My problem is that I want to implent Key-Shortcuts in my Silverlight application and there is a difference between calling Button_Save with Mouse-Click or manuel call in own function.

By manuel call, the silverlight function has not the actual values in controls. Otherwise when I click the Button_Save with mouse (onClick).

Is there any chance to get the same to call the Button_Save event just like to click the button with mouse?

Thank's for help.
Patrik

Comment: Ok I think I find a way with Dispatcher.BeginInvoke.. Is that way correct?

Comment: Ok result is that the input of controls is not actual..